# Refresh Gridview on timer but keep state of expanded divs

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview running within an update panel and timer. It just displays the main heading and other primary parts, then beneath it is the remainder of the details. The user can click on the title div and it expands/hides the content beneath it with the following Javascript for each row

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.requestDetails').css('display', 'none');
        $('.expandResults').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().children(".requestDetails").slideToggle(500);
            $(this).toggleClass('slideSign');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="ctlTimer" Enabled="false" Interval="5000" OnTick="OnTimerIntervalElapse"/>
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ctlTimer" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate><asp:GridView ID="gvTasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvTasks_RowDataBound"
            OnRowCommand="gvTasks_RowCommand" 
            OnRowCreated="gvTasks_RowCreated" CssClass="gvGridTasksActive">
            <Columns><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="RequestSent">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="expandResults" id="expandResults">
                            <div class="title">Title stuff..
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeStamp">Timestamp stuff..
                            </div>
                            </div>

                        <br class="clearfloat" />
                        <div class="requestDetails" id="requestDetails">
                        <br /><hr />
                            Request details stuff....</div></ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

The problem I have is when the page does a refresh it is expanding all of my rows with the expanded div. Is there a way that I can have the page do an auto refresh so my c# can rebind the grid if a new record is added its displayed but it remembers what was currently expanded or not?

Answer (score 0):

A Suggestion would be to use iCallBack with proper parameters and get the modified data asynchronously and with the help of JavaScript, append/remove/modify that data in your grid.

You could get the data asynchronously and check for each row for changes and bind the new HTML accordingly.

Posting code would be difficult